# How to acces to openstack container from c program?

Tags: c, openstack, openstack-swift

I have the task of downloading files from openstack container, but i can not find the libary that can connect to container. Maybe someone know something about that kind libary's?

sorry for broken english :)

Comment: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/SDKs#C